# Using TQDM almost doubles the file size of my GET request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tqdm

I've been writing a code to download GRIB (weather) file of of the internet for future use. Right now, I'm only a the stage of downloading and writing in the right folder but for some reason when I ue TQDM for a progress bar, the file size almost doubles. Without the progress the file size is fine.

With the following code I get a 2.3MB file.

```
import datetime
fsearch = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d00')
def sfc_pres():
    id = fsearch
    url = 'https://dd.weather.gc.ca/ensemble/geps/grib2/raw/00/000/CMC_geps-raw_PRES_SFC_0_latlon0p5x0p5_{0}_P000_allmbrs.grib2'.format(id)
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    stat=r.status_code
    while stat:
        if stat==200:
            print('Fichier trouvé, téléchargement')
        elif stat==404:
            print('Fichier introuvable')
        break
    id = fname
    with open(r'C:\Users\JM\Desktop\GRIB\Pression de surface 00UTC {0}.grib2'.format(id) , 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

If I use TQDM for a progress bar like so, I get a 4.5MB file.

```
import datetime
fsearch = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d00')
fname = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
def sfc_pres():
   id = fsearch
   url = 'https://dd.weather.gc.ca/ensemble/geps/grib2/raw/00/000/CMC_geps-raw_PRES_SFC_0_latlon0p5x0p5_{0}_P000_allmbrs.grib2'.format(id)
   r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
   stat=r.status_code
   while stat:
       if stat==200:
           print('Fichier trouvé, téléchargement')
       elif stat==404:
           print('Fichier introuvable')
       break
   from tqdm import tqdm
   total_size_in_bytes= int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0))
   block_size = 1024
   progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_size_in_bytes, unit='iB', unit_scale=True)
   id = fname
   with open(r'C:\Users\JM\Desktop\GRIB\Pression de surface 00UTC {0}.grib2'.format(id) , 'wb') as f:
       f.write(r.content)
       for data in r.iter_content(block_size):
           progress_bar.update(len(data))
           f.write(data)
   progress_bar.close()
   if total_size_in_bytes != 0 and progress_bar.n != total_size_in_bytes:
       print("Échec du téléchargement")
```

My troubleshooting got me to know it was within the TQDM code but I can't find why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `r.iter_content` you shouldn't also call `f.write(r.content)` - then you're writing the data twice (and lose the streaming behavior you're trying to get).